# unable to load model using hmvc in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

unable to load model using hmvc in codigniter.

Here is my controller **users.php** (application/modules/users/controllers/users.php)

```
class Users extends MX_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('users_view');
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->load->model('model/mdl', TRUE);
        $data['result']=$this->mdl->listTable();
        $this->load->view('pages/listTable', $data);
    }
}
```

and the model **mdl.php** (application/modules/users/model/mdl.php)

```
class Mdl extends CI_Model{
    function listTable(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query)  return $query->result_array();
        else        return false;

    }
}
```

all i am getting is

`Unable to locate the model you have specified: mdl`

my PHP version is 5.1.6 and CI: 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the model like this, if it's in the same module:

```
$this->load->model('mdl');
```

Or, if you want to load the model from a different module, you need to specify the module that the model belongs to in the path, like this:

```
$this->load->model('users/mdl');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to load a model, here's the best syntax if you load the model in the same module :

```
$this->load->model('mdl_model');
```

And if you want to load it from a different module :

```
$this->load->model('users/mdl_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please check model file name and class name must be start with capital
>   latter and   **$this->load->model('users/Mdl','mdl');**
>
> Pass second parameter for converting  model name

your modelfile naming must be Mdl.php